# Howto determine the first and last row qt model/view

Tags: c++, qt

I'm building an filebrowser based upon the QAbstractListModel and QListView.

As you know what is displayed can change, by making the window bigger, or by scrolling.

How can I determine the first and the last entry (or index) actually displayed. Do I have to program that myself?

Added later:

see for full description:

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/26497/

Thanks in advance,

Stef Bon
Voorburg
the Netherlands

Comment: You are not being very clear, why do you want to know the first and last entry?  The view knows what is visible at any particular moment and requests data from the model regarding it.

Comment: Why is it important to you why I want to know the first and the last item? Of course there is a reason, but too complicated to explain, and the question is very clear and obvious.

Comment: I ask because your question sounds a classic XY problem, so I wanted more detail from you before I answered.  I suggest that you do not give obnoxious replies to perfectly reasonable comments, otherwise you may find people reluctant to help you...

Comment: Ok, you want more detail. Why don't you say so. You start your comment  by sayng I'm not clear. That is not very polite, if not blunt, if it is only more detail you want. I suggest you being a bit more polite.

Comment: Ok, the backend data can change: entries can be added, changed or removed.

Comment: Suppose an entry is added, and the view can only hold 40 entries. When it's in the view (say around the tenth position), the way to go is to add a row (beginInertRow...), but when it's not in the view that is not required, as I understand it. Indices are (re) evaluated when the layout is changed/scrolled as I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason provided in the comments is not adequate; the model is supposed to call `beginInsertRows`/`endInsertRows` at any time, even if the range where you are inserting items is not currently visible in the view. There are multiple reasons for that (proxy models, `QPersistentModelIndex` instances, selection handling, `QAbstractItemView`'s internal housekeeping, caching of already rendered items etc).

The MVC API in Qt is designed so that the model is not supposed to know about what the view is currently showing. The contracts expressed in the `QAbstractItemModel` specify that the model "just" has to keep the rest of the world updated by calling the protected methods (which emit the `rowsInserted` etc signals, among other things). If you ever find yourself in a situation where you start thinking "hey, if only I knew how this model was displayed in the attached view", the correct thing is to make sure you are using the existing API effectively. As an example, a very common problem is that the programmer finds out that their model's `data()` method is called too often, for each item in a list, for example. The typical reason for this is that the corresponding `QListView` needs to know how much space to reserve for each item so that the scrollbar size can be determined. A correct way for this is to either return usable data for the `SizeHintRole`, or set the view's `uniformRowSizes` to `true`.

Comment: Aha thanks a lot. You say that the model does not know what is displayed (what makes sense), but does that also count for the view? Doesn't have the view properties like firstIndex and lastIndex, and sgnals when these change?? That would be very very usefull.

Comment: The view obviously knows what it is showing. The point is that the view does not make that information available to the outside world. I claim that in most of the situations, the programmer does not actually need to know that and if they think they do, they are typically wrong.

Comment: Ok, I think I can make it work, but I have to use an extra hashtable, which matches the entry to a row. This is a bit extra, and I hoped this is not necessary, since there is already the index.

Comment: And an extra threat(s) which watches changes in the backend and emits the right signals (remove/add rows..) to the model.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking in there, but the ``internalId()`` or ``internalPointer()`` are the ways on how to find out "what that index points to". A ``QModelIndex`` is just a temporary way of conveying that information. Read about the whole thing in the Qt's documentation.

Comment: Ok let me explain. When an entry is added, it's the question to which row it has to be added. The function beginInsertRows requires the row as parameter. Now, with the entry (to be added) the next entry is known, and when that is not present, then the previous is known. This is by design of the data. It's possible to determine the row by walking through the existing rows sequentally, but this takes a lot of time. Beter is to use a hashtable, which points to a number of elements. Every element points to an index. It's required that it's possible to point to an index. Is this possible?

Comment: You seem to be missing some of the basic concepts on subclassing the ``QAbstractItemModel``. Please read the documentation on [model-view programming in Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html) carefuly **and** study the provided examples and demo models; that is the only way to understand this. It **is** a complex code.

Comment: Sorry I did. If I'm missing some point please explain it. I've read a lot of documentation, end based my program on the fetchmore example.

Comment: And the documentation is not always clear: for example " However, the fetchMore() function is only called when the model is being populated incrementally." How can the model determine it's populated incrementally?? There is no slot saying "model data incremented".